# How to add Zigzag line or layer between two images in android?

Tags: android, canvas, view, android-imageview, zigzag

I am working on **Merging or Collage** types frames in android and I have Zigzag view between them, How could I get Zigzag pattern between the images.
Here is an example, What I required:

[image: Example]

Note: Here are two images, they should scale, rotate or touched.